# Unloading/Removing content from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, iframe

Is there anyway to unload a page that has been loaded inside an iframe? I do not want to  change the iframe src to a blank page if possible. I am basically looking for something that will do something like this `$('#frameID').attr("src","");` except that code does not seem to clear the previously loaded page.

Is there a `"unload"` function that I can call which will reset the iframe so that it does not have any content loaded inside?

Comment: you can just remove and create new one iframe.

Comment: `$("#frameID").attr("src", "")` works just fine for me on Firefox 11.  If you really want a blank iframe, you might also want to try setting the `src` to `about:blank` instead of an empty string.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen `about:blank` works wonders!!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The other solutions use `innerHTML`, which won't always work in XHTML. They also only clear `document.body` (anything in the `<head>` is still present). Here is a solution that uses the DOM:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame"),
frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
```

This solution uses `innerHTML`:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame"),
frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: As [AJ Ostergaard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/63306/aj-ostergaard) pointed out in an [edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/227353), this can only work if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page. I rejected the edit for being misplaced, but his point is still correct and worth mentioning.

Comment: @EliGrey This works perfectly for unloading (the first, non-innerHTML, solution), but once I have unloaded the content from an iframe, I cannot load anything back in by setting src... the iframe remains blank. How might I reuse the iframe once I have done this?

Answer (score 11):

If you **generate dynamically the content of your iframe**, all scripts/variable loaded will leak from one write to another. Thus the solution provided by @Eli of clearing the dom element **will not work**.

**In short:**

To clean, wrap your iframe into a div element and replace its dom content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="test"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To clean:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.innerHTML= "<iframe id='test'></iframe>";
```

**In details: Demo of script leakage**

Example of script leakage between two iframe writes (tested with Chrome):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('test');

// define variable 'a'
var content = "<html><body><script>var a=555;</script></body></html>";

iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

// uncomment this to clean the iframe
//document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML= "<iframe id='test'></iframe>";

// write 'a' if defined
var content2 = "<html><body><div id='content'></div><script>document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=typeof a === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : a;</script></body></html>";

var iframe2 = document.getElementById('test');
iframe2.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe2.contentWindow.document.write(content2);
iframe2.contentWindow.document.close();
```

If you run this code, you will see the output of the second iframe is `555` although it has been defined in the first iframe.

If you uncomment the middle part it will work as expected.

Related question: [Avoiding memory leaks loading content into an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644462/avoiding-memory-leaks-loading-content-into-an-iframe)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any alternative without removing the iframe?

Comment: You saved the day month year for me. Thank you so much. Works like a charm. This should be accepted answer imo.

Comment: "wrap your iframe into a div element and replace its dom content" No need to add a wrapper element. You can use the `outerHTML` property: `iframe.outerHTML = "<iframe id='test'></iframe>";` See [Iframe document write doesn't update JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76724943/478018) for similar ideas.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html('');
```

It only clears innerHTML of your  tag inside  and not actually unload your iframe so you can reuse your iframe without reloading it and its working in all browsers and quite simple!!

Comment: But this only works if the iframe is loaded from the same domain, right?

Answer (score 5):

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
frame.src = "about:blank";
```

This worked from me and prevented memory leaks too.
In my case I had to destroy the parent too. In that case you have to destroy the parent with some delay to prevent memory leak

Comment: By 'parent' do you mean the parent page, or parent element in the DOM that contained the IFRAME tag?

Comment: The parent element that contains the iframe

Answer (score 4):

> $('#frameID').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
>   = '';

As with any iframe, this only works if you're on the same domain.

Answer (score 4):

Removing and recreating the iframe is the safest solution here.

By removing only the `innerHTML` of the iframe you don't flush the variables stored, the bound eventListeners etc.

Be careful with this, it might cause a lot of problems (like memory leaks, multiple triggers of the same event etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#frameId").contents().find("div#SomeDIVinsideFrame").remove(); // removes some div content inside iframe

$("#FrameId").remove(); // removes frame
```

had same problem to show iframe news on http://www.livepage.info

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, cleared everything within the iframe tag; body, head, html and all:

```
$("iframe").contents().empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had previously loaded content by setting the `src` property of the iframe, you cannot empty the content as it is a violation of cross site scripting.

You can then just set the `src` property to `''` which will make the browser discard the whole content.

```
$('iframe').prop('src', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the document of the frame:

```
var frame = $('#frameId').get(0);
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
```

Then, blank it:

```
frameDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "";
```

I think this should work too:

```
$('body', frameDoc).html("");
```

Now, you might want to do something with any scripts that might be loaded in the head, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger unload event of that iframe like

```
$('body').trigger('unload');
```

and then remove the iframe from the parent window and reload a new iframe with new src when needed.

```
$('#iframe_wrapper').html('');
$('#iframe_wrapper').html('<iframe src="...">');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{

var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

//Do whatever you need with the content    

}
```

**it will definitely work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**