# jQuery - Delete invisible div inside iFrame after X seconds?

Tags: jquery

Basing on this script:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8cVD/)

```
var W=0, H=0, X=0, Y=0;
$(".iframe").each(function(i,el){
   W = $(el).width();
   H = $(el).height();
   X = $(el).position().left;
   Y = $(el).position().top;
   $(this).after('<div class="overlay" />');
    $(this).next('.overlay').css({
        width: W,
        height: H,
        left: X,
        top: Y        
    });
});

// TRACK MOUSE POSITIONS (the overlay will prevent clicks on iframe page)
var mx = 0, my = 0;
$('.overlay').on('mousemove click',function(e){
    mx = e.clientX - $(this).position().left;
    my = e.clientY - $(this).position().top;

    if(e.type==='click'){
        alert('clicked at: X='+mx+' Y='+my)
    }        
});
```

Is it possible to auto-delete the invisible div after X seconds?

Thanks

Comment: i'm wrong, when i say div i referer to the layer that coats the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following as part of the on() callback.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
                     $('.overlay').remove();
                  }, 10000); //10 sec delay
```

See [setTimeout docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) for details. Also you'll need to remove the label that shows the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** If you want to remove content of an iframe you can follow this link:
[Unloading/Removing content from an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe)
You should put it in a timer like this:

```
// delete after 3 seconds.
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},3000);
function myTimer()
{
   // remove the div
   $('#yourDiv').remove();
}
```

For more information about timing in javascript you can follow this link: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)
Hope to help.