# Avoiding memory leaks loading content into an iframe

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, iframe

I am working on an embedded system that presents content in an iframe. It uses signalR (which is based on ajax) and jquery. The browser gets slower and slower, and the memory usage goes up and up, as the hours go by. So I am looking to remove all potential memory problems.

When the new page is loaded into the iframe, I attach click and focus event handlers.

Just before the iframe page is to be replaced, I un-attach them.

However, if I inspect $.cache (while testing on a PC with firefox, so not completely the same as my real system) it still shows $.cache gaining more and more elements each time the iframe is reload.

Is this the correct way to do things? Is there anything else I can try? Why is $.cache growing?

(In case your are interested I am using a raspberry pi (runs linux) with the Midori browser, though there is a choice of other (mostly web-kit) browsers that I could use).

Javascript I use to change the iframe contents...

```
hubProxy.client.loadPage = function (pageFilename, pageType) {
    frameNode = $("#myIframe").contents();
    $("a", frameNode).off();  
    $("#myIframe")[0].src = pageFilename;
};
```

Comment: You are storing frameNode globally, is that intended?

Comment: @kevinb: re-using globals would actually reduce un-collected garbage.

Comment: The only time entries get added to the cache are when events or data are added to an element, and it gets cleared when that element is removed ***by jquery***. Since you are just changing the src of the iframe, most likely that cleanup isn't happening. That'd be my first guess, without seeing much more of your code or going to the src. A test for that would be to replace `.off()` with `.remove()`

Comment: @Kevin B, no, wasnt meant ot be a global, thanks for spotting that

Comment: @KevinB, I didnt understand your last comment. When you say "Since you are just changing the src of the iframe, most likely that cleanup isn't happening" Do you mean it is understandable cleanup is not happening and I should be doing more to promote clean up? Or are you saying that it it isnt happening but it should be happening?

Comment: I'm saying the cleanup isn't happening.  By changing the src of the iframe, the elements are being removed, but the data jQuery is storing about those elements is not being removed.

Comment: Here's a good exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/TAE9y/ Note how when i removed 50 elements with jQuery, the cache had 50 less elements, however when i removed elements without jQuery, they remained in the cache.

Comment: If you'll notice though, adding another test for .off does properly remove them from the cache in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TAE9y/1/. however the fiddle of course isn't using an iframe, so i'm not sure how that would affect it. I'm also not sure what else your code might be doing that might be causing more data to be stored about the element in the cache.

Comment: @kevin b - I replaced .off() with .remove() and indeed $.cache is no longer growing - so thanks for that tip. I will run overnight to see if there is improvement. I just heard about $.cache the other day, is there anything else I can check to look for memory issues.

Comment: I think $.cache is the only one you'll have to look out for, as it's the only thing directly linked to the element. $.data stores it's data in said cache too.

Answer (score 3):

Write a wrapper div to hold your iframe container, such as...

```
<div id="myIframeWrapper"></div>
```

Now you can clean up after the previous iframe page, and this can be done by completely clearing out everything in the DOM related to the previous iframe, and then creating a fresh iframe by using a constructor when you invoke your loadPage function.

```
hubProxy.client.loadPage = function (pageFilename, pageType) {

    var myNewIframe = '<iframe id="myIframe" src="' + pageFilename + '"></iframe>';

    // Remove old iframe from the DOM and replace with new iframe
    if ($("#myIframe")) {
        $("#myIframeWrapper").empty().append( myNewIframe );
    }

    var frameNode = $("#myIframe").contents();
    $("a", frameNode).off();
};
```

You will notice that the original line assigning the iframe source has been removed, as it is already accounted for in the new constructor. This also has the benefit of being able to add other iframe attributes using the constructor, such as the iframe size, etc.

Comment: Any other alternative without using any wrapper?