# Error when trying to 'Unloading/Removing content from an iFrame'

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to remove the content from an iFrame and I get this SO question: [Unloading/Removing content from an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe). 
The problem is that when I'm trying to code the solutions given, I get this error on the debug console in the FireBug:  `Permission denied to access property 'document'`.

What I'm doing is this:

```
    var frame = document.getElementById("idFrame"),
        frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document; //error here
    frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
```

What is the problem here? What I'm doing wrong?

Same error when I tried to do:

```
$("#amadeusFrame").contents().find("body").html('');
```

Comment: A cross-domain access? If yes, [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) blocks the access to the iframe.

Comment: Exactly like @Teemu says - read the third comment for the accepted answer for question Teemu linked. And of course try my solution if you want to wipe out everything from iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. Try:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("idFrame");
frame.src = "about:blank";
```

You can't play with the content of iframe because it would be a vector for XSS attack.
You can do this only if the iframe source is in the same domain as containing document.