# Iframe is not releasing memory after closing the window

Tags: memory, iframe

I am facing issue on memory leakage in Chrome.
Steps.
1. I am opening other (BPM) application in iframe from my application. 
2. Before opening the iframe application, memory was 8.2 MB. When i opens up iframe memory reaches to 18 MB.
3. When i close the iframe window, memory should release and it should be back to 8.2 but its not happening. Memory is still 18 MB.

I tried many solutions but none is working. 
[Unloading/Removing content from an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe)

Can anyone helps me out on this.

Comment: Good question and welcome to stack overflow! If you want to help your question be a little better, try creating a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).