# Can I display an external div on my site?

Tags: html, razor

My company has two websites with mostly different content. But e. g. the imprint is the same. Is it possible to implement a div from site A in a div from site B?
I could use iframe but I do not need header and footer...

Thanks

Philipp

Comment: Maybe you can use this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Could you please help with a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was thinking of in the link I provided :

```js
const frame = document.getElementById("frameID");
frame.getElementById("headerID").remove();
frame.getElementById("footerID").remove();
```

I didn't test it so it may not work

Comment: Might be a dumb question but I am new to this. What is `document`?

Comment: Javascript allows you to manipulate what we call the DOM (Document object model), which basically represents all divs and elements of your page as javascript objects. Here the document.getElementById will look for an element with id "frameID" in the DOM.