# Memory leak when a iframe with url pointing to a react app is removed and added

Tags: reactjs, performance, iframe, memory-leaks, reselect

I have a react-redux app which runs inside iframe, Iframe with same exact url is getting removed and added back by the parent application but doing so is causing memory footprint and CPU usage growing as we keep doing more number of times (reaches 5 GB after trying around 100 times), I believe it may not be something related to just react but in general as well, any help would be much appreciated.

**React App in  iframe**:

```
const postMessage = () => {
    window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ type: "TYPEB", message: "some message to parent" }), location.origin);
}
const messageEventHandler = (event) => {
    //event handling code
}
const addMessageEventListenerFromParent = () => {
    window.addEventListener("message", messageEventHandler);
};

const rootComponent = () =>
    useEffect(() => {
        // adding event listeners
        addMessageEventListenerFromParent();
        postMessage();
        return () => {
            console.log("unmounting the app");
            removeMessageEventListenerFromParent();
        };
    }, []);
}
```

**Parent App (React app):**

```js
const Iframe = (props) => {
    const iframeRef = useRef(null);

    const postMessage = (message) => {
        if (iframeEl?.current.contentWindow?.postMessage) {
            iframeEl.current.contentWindow.postMessage(message, location.origin);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        postMessage({
            type: "TYPEA",
            payload: somePayload,
        })
    }, [props.propA])

    const memoizedIframe = useMemo(() => (
        <iframe ref= { iframeRef } key = { key } className = "iframetask" src = { sourceUri } />
        ), [inputs]);
    return memoizedIframe;
}

export default memo(Iframe);
```

This is a sample code of my app (running in iframe), return function (cleanup function) not getting executed when the iframe is removed and added back by parent app, this means the component is not getting unmounted but getting mounted as iframe is re-inserted.

Comment: You have a react app running inside a frame? What for? Also, what useEffect cleanup are your referring to? Having some code to show could help helping you :)

Comment: Hi @ale917k, I have updated the description and provided a sample code

Comment: if I can know, why are you running react in an iframe?

Comment: @RanuVijay this is our product usecase, react app is micro frontend app runs in iframe, I believe this is something to do with iframe garbage collection on browser between unloading a iframe and loading a iframe

Comment: Check if [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307165/unloading-removing-content-from-an-iframe) helps you to remove iframe. Id content of i frame is removed properly, react will use unmound, I guess :)

Comment: This is most likely caused by the parent application retaining a reference to the iframe that's hosting your react app - not your react app - see [this article](https://docs.pega.com/performance/common-javascript-memory-leak-patterns#:~:text=Iframe%20leak,collected%20without%20requiring%20internal%20cleanup.) for examples of common patterns that can cause this. It's hard to debug further without a [minimal reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though.

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier, i have update the code, please check, we are not doing anything as such mentioned in the article in the parent app

Comment: Sorry this might be a tall order - but the code you posted won't run (for a variety of reasons - `inputs`, `iFrameEl`, `somepayload` etc. are not defined, for example). I can tell that some of these changes are simplifications intended to make it readable, but root cause might be concealed in these simplifications. Is there a way you could get a (simplified) version of the problem actually running on codesandbox.io (or something similar)?

Comment: You might also consider using the chrome dev tools on the real app (where you see the problem) to track memory allocation over time, as described [here](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-find-memory-leaks-in-javascript-b898c85995a3), which might give you some clues.